# How to judge the extreme point of a function of two variables when $b^2-ac=0$

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus

As we all know, the sufficient condition of the extreme point of a function of two variables is depended on $z=b^2-ac$. When $z>0$, the extreme point exists.

However, how can I judge the existence of the extreme point when $z=0$? I would appreciate it if anyone could show some examples about my question.

Thank u all, my good friends:)

Addition:
$a=\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}, b=\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x \partial y}, c=\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial y^2}$.

a function of two variables means functions like $f(x,y)$

Comment: What do you mean by a function of two variables? what are the variables?

Comment: And what is the function?

Comment: Oh just fix some miscellaneous description......